# "Windows was unexpected at this time" error when trying to compare 2 strings in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, windows-7, windows-xp

I am writing a batch script to use USMT to update computers from XP to 7. Because USMT has a scanstate component that needs to be run before the OS upgrade and a loadstate computer that has to be run after the OS upgrade I am trying to use an if statement to check what the operating system is and then run the proper commands. I am new to batch files but from everything I have been reading it seems like I am writing it properly but I am obviously messing up somewhere. I am getting a "Windows is unexpected at this time error." I also know that the variables are being set properly because of the pause commands that I included. I also tried using `IF %WINVERSION% == %XP% goto XPTRUE/WIN7TRUE` and enclosing everything within the brackets under a `:XPTRUE/WIN7TRUE` but that gives the same error.

```
::Don't have commands print...only outputs are printed
@echo off
:: Set constants
SET XP=Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
SET WIN7=Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
SET XPUSMTLOCATION=C:\Program Files\USMT\Binaries\v4\x86
SET 7USMTLOCATION=C:\Program Files (x86)\USMT\Binaries\v4\amd64
SET BACKUPLOACTION=\\[SERVER IP]\z$\UserAccountBackUps\Backups
SET LOCALBACKUPLOCATION=C:\Backup\USMT
SET NASBACKUPLOCATION=S:\UserAccountBackUps\Backups
@PAUSE
::Get the current version of Windows batch file is running on and store it in WINVERSION
FOR /f "delims=" %%A IN ('ver') DO @SET WINVERSION=%%A
echo %WINVERSION%
PAUSE
::Get the MAC address of the computer and store it in MACA
FOR /F %%A IN ('getmac') DO @SET MACA=%%A
echo The MAC Address is: %MACA%
:: Tell user about script
echo This is a script designed to migrate computers with one network card from Windows XP to Windows 7 using USMT, this script should not be used with computers that have multiple network cards
echo Xp is %XP%
echo 7 is %WIN7%
::Check to see if the current version is XP
PAUSE

IF %WINVERSION% == %XP% (
echo This is windows XP
::Change directory to the location of USMT files
cd %XPUSMTLOCATION%
::Run scanstate to create backup
scanstate.exe C:\Backup /i:"\\[SERVER IP]\z$\UserAccountBackUps\USMT_XML_Files\MigApp.xml" /i:"\\[SERVER IP]\z$\UserAccountBackUps\USMT_XML_Files\MigDocs.xml" /i:"\\[SERVER IP]\z$\UserAccountBackUps\USMT_XML_Files\MigUser.xml" /o /v:2
::Change directory to the location of where the USMT backup is
cd %LOCALBACKUPLOCATION%
::Rename the backup to the MAC Address
rename USMT.MIG %MACA%.MIG
::Map the NAS to a drive because xcopy can not take IP addresses
echo Mapping NAS to drive
::NAS is mapped to drive S, if S is used for something else change s below to different letter
net use s: \\[SERVER IP]\z$
echo Prepairing to copy backup to NAS
::Use xcopy to transfer backup file the /v ensures the files are identical
::This must be done this way because if USMT tries to backup directly to the NAS it tries to overwrite all existing files
xcopy %LOCALBACKUPLOCATION%\%MACA%.MIG %NASBACKUPLOCATION% /v
echo The copy has completed, run this batch file again after OS Upgrade
)

IF %WINVERSION% == %WIN7% (
echo This is Windows 7
PAUSE
)
```

When I run this on my Windows 7 computer I get this:

[image]

I get the same output on my XP computer except it tells me the current version is xp instead. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line below:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%A IN ('ver') DO @SET WINVERSION=%%A
```

stores in WINVERSION variable a string that contain several words separated by spaces, for example:

```
SET WINVERSION=Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
```

This way, the line below:

```
IF %WINVERSION% == %XP% (
```

is expanded to:

```
IF Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200] == Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600] (
```

that, of course, cause a syntax error! Type: `IF /?` for further details.

The way to compare two strings that may contains spaces, is enclosing they in quotes:

```
IF "%WINVERSION%" == "%XP%" (
```